# dired-quick-sort - sort by name not working

Tags: dired

Linux Mint 20.1

Emacs 26.3

In folder `temp` I have some files.
Here is what it looks like (sort by name) in file manager Nemo

[image: Nemo]

Sort by name:

**how.build.txt** is first. Nice.

Now same folder in dired mode

[image: Dired mode]

As you can see I select:

*Sort by : version (natural)*

I add new file **whatsnew2.txt**

and here result

[image: add new whatsnew2 file]

But file **how.build.txt** is not first file in folder.
It's AFTER file **WHATSNEW.txt** and BEFORE **whatsnew2.txt**

Why?

P.S.

```
'(dired-listing-switches "-alFh")
```

And in my init.el

```
(require 'dired-quick-sort)
(dired-quick-sort-setup)
;; to save sort after reset Emacs
(savehist-mode 1)
```

P.P.S
If I comment in init.el

```
;;(dired-quick-sort-setup)
```

and now sort correct:

[image: Correct sort]

Why and how fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `dired-listing-switches`? Are you on Linux or something else? What locale are you using? (if you are on linux, you can say `locale` to find out the locale you are using)

Comment: @NickD I use Linux Mint 20.1, locale = LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US. I'm not found "dired-listing-switches"

Comment: The question is unclear, so it risks being closed. You're clearly not using `emacs -Q` (no init file), but you don't specify your configuration (especially wrt Dired - what you have is not vanilla). Provide a step-by-step recipe from `emacs -Q` to reproduce the problem, saying what you do at each step, what you see, and what you expected to see. But first, narrow down your config to just what is needed to show the problem. The problem does not exist with vanilla Emacs (`emacs -Q`).

Comment: `C-h v dired-listing-switches`. `C-h f dired`. Each of those describes the switches and how to affect the listing behavior.

Comment: @Drew  '(dired-listing-switches "-alFh")

Comment: Don't tell me. Put all relevant info in your question itself. Thx.

Comment: @NickD I was updated my post

Comment: @Drew I found the problem line. But how fix this?

Comment: You might try asking the maintainers of library `dired-quick-sort`. At least now you know that it's causing the problem, at least in the way you're using it. Unless someone here knows about that library, you might not find a good answer here. (But I hope you will.)